# Error while profiling with VS: Unable to open profiler driver

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, profiling

I am running Windows 8 with UAC *completely disabled* which is possible to do by changing a [registry setting](http://www.eightforums.com/system-security/2434-disable-uac-completely.html) (setting it to "Never notify" no longer completely disables it in Windows 8).

When I try to profile C# code through Visual Studio I get the following error (clicking yes doesn't resolve the problem):

> Unable to open profiler driver, would you like to upgrade credentials of [username]?

Running `vsperfcmd /Admin:Driver,START` from the command line says:

> Error VSP1449: Unable to start VSPerfDrv100. This driver has been
>   blocked from loading Try using the /Admin switch of VSPerfCmd from an
>   elevated environment.

I obviously am using an elevated environment, since with UAC completely disabled I no longer have two security tokens but only the administrator security token.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @Hans: with the registry setting it is possible to fully disable it. In fact, store apps cannot run (which I consider a feature)

Comment: The opposite: everything runs as admin, whether you choose run as admin or not

Comment: @Hans: no -- before EnableLUA, I had to run visual studio as admin, the cmd line as admin, etc, or I would keep getting access denied to several files. EnableLUA works well in windows 8 (source that says it was disabled in win7?), and after it's set to 0 you no longer have two user tokens. The only problem that I've ever had is the vs profiler service.

Comment: This blog post seems to imply the driver is simply blocked by Windows 8: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8.aspx

Comment: @Simon: why not post that as an answeR?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The blog post here '[The Visual Studio Profiler on Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20121216041713/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8.aspx)' states this:

> Windows 8 added logic to prevent all incompatible versions of the
> profiling driver from starting (2010, 2008, and 2005).
>
> This means that when you try to start profiling with an incompatible
> version you will receive the message “*Error VSP1398: The monitor was
> unable to start the VS performance driver. Access is denied. Consider
> using the /Admin:Driver,Start and /Admin:Security options of VSPerfCmd
> from an elevated environment.*”
>
> Which will result in the following behavior when running Visual Studio
> 2010 (or earlier) on Windows 8.
>
> - CPU Sampling, .NET Memory Allocation, and Concurrency profiling will    fail to start on Windows 8. The only workaround on Windows 8
>   is to    use Visual Studio 2012 Professional or higher, or to profile
>   on    Windows 7.
> - Instrumentation profiling can be launched, but the application and    elapsed times will be exactly the same.

Comment: link is dead 'This page has been disabled'

Comment: @justromagod - the link has reappeared on archives, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "Full Controll" permissions to the directory where the driver "VSPerfDrv100.sys" is located.

You can find this using `"sc qc VSPerfDrv100"`.

For an x64 PC it should be `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64"`

Comment: Dont work too:
sc qc VSPerfDrv90
 [SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS
 SERVICE_NAME: VSPerfDrv90
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 0   IGNORE
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64\VSPerfDrv90.sys
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Performance Tools Driver 9.0
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME :VSPerfSys90